# pgfplots: Problem with ticks in logarithmic scale - math parse error

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmathparse

Why do I get the error

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '0.005,0.0005' as a floating po
int number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ',0.0005'..
```

when `pdflatex`ing the following document?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\xtickdef{0.005,0.0005}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmode=log,xtick={\xtickdef}]
    \addplot table {
      0.0001 10
      0.001 20
      0.01 15
    }; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error disappears if I don't use `\xtickdef` but supply the values literally as `xtick={0.005,0.0005}`.

The reason why I thought that macros in `xtick` are expanded before the list is processed: My construction works when removing `xmode=log`, i.e., there seems to be a difference in how the ticks are processed in linear and in logarithmic scale.

Is this a bug in `pgfplots`, or is it just lucky coincidence that it works in non-logarithmic scale?

Comment: The four numbers that you see in the error message are the contents of `\slavextick` that you compute before `\begin{document}`. If you replace `xtick=\slavextick` in the definition of the style `slave axis` by `xtick={599.9991,350.0001,200.00018,150.00032}`, your document compiles fine. (I'm just trying to localize the error a bit, this is not meant as a solution. It might well be a bug if it works in the non-logarithmic scale.)

Comment: That's odd!! I'm getting the numbers i want to get using 

`\i in {599.9991,350.0001,200.00018,150.00032} % xtick for the slave axis`

Guess is something related with the ticks parser. Thanks gernot!

Comment: I completely rewrote your post and reduced it to a rather minimal example. I think that it is easier to attract help this way. But feel free to revert to the original post.

Comment: Because it is a log plot all the elements in the `xtick=<coordinate list>` are transformed by `log()`. When the elements of `xtick` are given by a command, it seems, that the whole list is given to `log()` at once which of course doesn't work. Because I am not sure if this is a bug, we will see what Christian will say about it. I reported this issue to the [tracker as bug 135](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/135/).

Comment: As @StefanPinnow noted correctly, this is some kind of expansion issue: it should have been expanded before handed over to the log method. I'll see what I do about it. For the time being, you could try `xtick/.expand once={\xtickdef}`. The key handler `.expand once` is evaluated _before_ `xtick`, and it replaces the first macro in the argument by its expansion. That should do the job.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been solved in the comments.